# How to make always one panel open in custom make angular-bootstrap accordion

Tags: angularjs

Is there way to make that one accordion panel is always open. I create custom directive which is override one in bootstrap-tpls and its working ok. Following  directive:

```
.directive('myAccordionGroup', function () {
        return {
            require: '^myAccordion', // We need this directive to be inside an accordion
            restrict: 'EA',
            transclude: true, // It transcludes the contents of the directive into the template
            replace: true, // The element containing the directive will be replaced with the template
            templateUrl: function (element, attrs) {
                return attrs.templateUrl || './template/accordion/accordion-group.html';
            },
            scope: {
                viewlink: '@', // Interpolate the viewlink attribute onto this scope
                heading: '@', // Interpolate the heading attribute onto this scope
                isOpen: '=?',
                isDisabled: '=?'
            },
            controller: function () {
                this.setHeading = function (element) {
                    this.heading = element;
                };
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, accordionCtrl) {
                accordionCtrl.addGroup(scope);

                scope.$watch('isOpen', function (value) {
                    if (value) {
                        accordionCtrl.closeOthers(scope);
                    }
                });

                scope.toggleOpen = function () {
                    if (!scope.isDisabled) {
                        scope.isOpen = !scope.isOpen;
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is going to work :

```
scope.toggleOpen = function () {
     if (!scope.isDisabled && scope.isOpen === false) {
          scope.isOpen = !scope.isOpen;
     }
};
```